# disabling few buttons from group of buttons React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax

I have an array of data

```
const projectTypeValues = [
{ name: 'Hour', value: 'hour'},
{ name: 'Day', value: 'day'},
{ name: 'Session', value: 'session'},
{ name: 'project', value: 'project'}]
```

From there I am showing the buttons in a material ui buttonGroup through an loop.

```
{projectTypeValues.map(element=>
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary">{element.name}</Button>
        )}
```

how do i make a couple or few buttons from this loop disabled while others are active?

I want to show all the 4buttons but other 3 buttons will be disabled and only session will be active

Thanks for your help

Comment: you can keep another property in `projectTypeValues`, let say `disabled`. then you can set it direclty to the button. `<Button variant="contained" color="primary" disabled={element.disabled}>{element.name}</Button>`

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera that would be so great, but in this scenario I cant do that, is there any way doing it with indexing or something?

Comment: can you explain which buttons you want to display and the condition for that please?

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera I want to show all the 4buttons but other 3 buttons will be disabled and only session will be active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
{
    projectTypeValues.map(element => (
        <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            disabled={element.value !== "session"}
        >
            {element.name}
        </Button>
    ));
}
```

Comment: @Zeed Tanue, check this out!!